# Does it makes sense to write minidump on Unhandled Exception in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

It seems when I'm in exception handler like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Or like this:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
```

The stack was already unwind to call my custom unhandled exception handler. Seems it doesn't make sense to write a minidump at this point cause the stack was already unwind. 
Without unwinding the stack application can't understand whether this exception was unhandled or not.

Even if I can see stack in UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject I can't get minidump at exact place where application crashed.

Is there another way?

I know I can ask system to write a dump but I should be Administrator for that.

UPDATE:

Ok. I've got an idea ) Would be nice if in FirstChanceException handler I can walk stack back and see if this exception is unhandled or not. But this should be fast enough to work in production.

Comment: What is *minidump* and why do you care about stack? `Exception` itself contains `StackTrace`.

Comment: Look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dondu/archive/2010/10/24/writing-minidumps-in-c.aspx. Exceptions contains StackTrace and you can say ( for example ) that NullPointerException occured in some function. But with minidump you can see exact variable and environment where this exception occured.

Comment: Only write a minidump in the handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  The DispatcherUnhandledException handler is not useful for that.  Best avoided completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`FirstChanceException` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception), which is raised before the stack is unwound.

Comment: IIRC `FirstChanceException` will be fired even when exception is handled.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes; if you want to catch it before the stack unwind, there is no way to tell whether it will be handled.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But writing a minidump for every FirstChanceException is a waste of resources.

Comment: @norekhov: You cannot predict whether an exception will be handled before the stack unwinds.  What do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way to do this. Maybe check try/catches by reflection?
So the good answer to this question will be "No, you can't"

Comment: @norekhov: Unwinding the stack is exactly how the CLR searches for `catch` blocks.  Unless you write your own CLR (or use the out-of-proc debugger or profiling APIs), you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used dumps myself. It's usually enough to only know the place where exception occurs. But you are right, it would be much more handy to know values, etc. In the most recent version of error logger I even pass up to 3 optional parameters, which are dumped into a log, it helps. Something like (simplified):

```
public void Log(string tag, string message = "", Exception exception = null, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "",
    object param = null, object param2 = null, object param3 = null, object param4 = null)
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    var method = caller;
    if (param != null || param2 != null || param3 != null)
        method = string.Format("{0}({1}{2}{3}{4})", caller, param != null ? param : "", param2 != null ? ", " + param2 : "",
            param3 != null ? ", " + param3 : "", param4 != null ? ", " + param4 : "");
    try
    {
        ...
        if (exception != null)
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(_errorFileName, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1} {2}: {3}", time, tag, method, message));
                file.WriteLine(exception);
            }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

And usage is

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string file)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log("xml", exception: e, param: file, param2: typeof(T));
    }
    return default(T);
```

}

It is not an answer to your question, but a solution of how to live comfortably without dump.